# Uncaught reference Error: <mapkey> is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        var key = "testkey";
        var value = "testvalue";
        <apex:repeat value="{!timeSpent}" var="item">

            console.log(key);
            console.log(value);

            value = {!timeSpent[item]};
            key = {!item};

            console.log(key);
            console.log(value);
        </apex:repeat>

    });
```

timeSpent is a variable coming from the controller, a Salesforce Map of String to Decimal:

```
public Map<String, Decimal> timeSpent = new Map<String, Decimal(); 
// the map gets values via further code which works fine
```

When I execute the above javascript, console says:

2015-04-01 12:29:11.354cmRP_ResourceDashboard:45 testkey
2015-04-01 12:29:11.354cmRP_ResourceDashboard:46 testvalue
2015-04-01 12:29:11.356cmRP_ResourceDashboard:49 Uncaught ReferenceError: Geblockt is not defined

And I have no idea why. "Geblockt" is a key from that map, type string. The error only shows up for the keys of the map, not for the values. Any ideas, anyone?

Here is the debug from the Inspector (chrome)

```
 <script>
```

$(document).ready(function() {

```
  var key = "testkey";
  var value = "testvalue";

console.log(key);
console.log(value);

value = 0;
key = Geblockt; <---- HERE IS THE ERROR 

console.log(key);
console.log(value);

console.log(key);
console.log(value);

value = 5;
key = PR-122;

console.log(key);
console.log(value);
```

});

Comment: Use `key = "{!item}";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your example `Geblockt` be treated as variable which is not defined thus you are getting the error.

Assign It in quotes then it will be treated as string:

```
key = "{!item}";
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't know it's as easy as that. Can you explain the thought behind that? I'm rather new to javascript/jquery. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @lheinen, In this example `key = Geblockt;`, the `Geblockt` will be treated as variable on the otherhand `key = "Geblockt";` it will be treated as string